# Wrong rowCount when TableView is empty in PySIde

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I am using PySide, with a tableview and a model as shown below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, items, headers, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.items = items
        self.headers = headers

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.items)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.items[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        elif role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None

        return self.items[index.row()][index.column()]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.headers[section]

        return None
```

This is how I set the model, importing from models.py:

```
table_model = models.TableModel(data, headers)
self.tableView.setModel(table_model)
```

I get the tableview total rows:

```
table_model = tableview.model()
total_rows = table_model.rowCount(tableview)
```

If there is no data to display in the tableview, I set `data = [[]]`.
If I try to get the `rowCount`, I get `1` instead of `O`.

I realize it probably counts the nested list set as data.

So, what should I do to get the right rou count?

Answer (score 0):

Use `data = []` when there's no data, and then implement `columnCount` like this:

```
def columnCount(self, parent):
    return len(self.items[0]) if self.items else 0
```